# Is there a way to set a specific angle range for ItemTouchHelper.Callback to trigger onSwiped method?

Tags: android, itemtouchhelper

I have a vertical LinearLayout and inside it there is a RecyclerView which can be scrolled up and down, recently I attached an ItemTouchHelper Callback to the RecyclerView so that its items could be excluded by dragging them to the Left or to the Right, the problem is that the side draggings are to easly accepted and the movement gets misunderstood, interfering with the up and down scrolling actions, I've read ItemTouchHelper.Callback documentation and didn't find anything helpfull since the only attributes for drag options are UP and DOWN, END and START, RIGHT and LEFT.

I'm also thinking about removing the side swipe from the RecyclerView and attach it to the List as a whole, so showing other lists when doing it, would the solution be the same, since there would be those 2 possible movements anyway?

Here is my ItemTouch.Callback code:

```
 private void recyclerSwipe(){
        ItemTouchHelper.Callback itemTouch= new ItemTouchHelper.Callback() {
            /**getMovementFlags()
             * configuring the movements behavior
             * */
            @Override
            public int getMovementFlags(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
                /**ACTION_STATE_IDLE
                 * denies drag and drop movements
                 * (up, down, left, right)
                 * */
                int dragFlags=ItemTouchHelper.ACTION_STATE_IDLE;
                /**START,END
                 * allows swiping a recyclerView side to side
                 * */
                int swipeFlags=ItemTouchHelper.START|ItemTouchHelper.END;
                return makeMovementFlags(dragFlags,swipeFlags);
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onMove(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder1) {
                return false;
            }
            /**onSwiped()
             * setting reactions to user's drags
             * */
            @Override
            public void onSwiped(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
                deleteTransaction(viewHolder);
            }
        };
        /**attaching swipe to a recyclerView instance*/
        new ItemTouchHelper(itemTouch).attachToRecyclerView(recView);
    }
```